# How is an assign @property's setter implemented?

Tags: objective-c, properties, getter-setter, assign

Does the implementation of the setter first check if the new value is different than the old value before assigning the ivar to the new value?

Is there a documentation (or source code) reference that shows all the different permutations (depending on the attributes, `assign`, `retain`, etc.) of how a property is synthesized?

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine the assign setter checks previous values first. That would be a complete waste of CPU cycles, since the result will be the same either way. The documentation explicitly states the semantics of the various attributes, but it doesn't show you exactly what code is synthesized.

Comment: Wouldn't it save CPU cycles in the case that the new value is equal to the old value because then the CPU doesn't have to waste cycles resetting the instance variable to the new value?

Comment: @MattDiPasquale, in the case that they are the same, yes, you would save assigning to a variable, but you would pay for the conditional check beforehand. In the (most common) case where the values are different, you're now paying for the conditional and the assignment, doing more damage than good.

Comment: @Matt It should be fastest to simply set it (`load>mov`), rather than `load>load>compare>(branch ? mov : nop)`. With atomics, it's even more complex. The comparison is worthwhile when the operation is more significant (e.g. a retained or copied property). pseudo-asm.

Answer (score 1):

The [Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1) documentation explains this. The details of what actually happens are implementation specific.

> **copy**
> Specifies that a copy of the object should be used for
> assignment. The previous value is sent a release message. The copy is
> made by invoking the copy method. This attribute is valid only for
> object types, which must implement the NSCopying  protocol.
>
> **assign**
> Specifies that the setter uses simple assignment. This attribute is
> the default. You use this attribute for scalar types such as NSInteger
> and CGRect.
>
> **retain**
> Specifies that retain should be invoked on the
> object upon assignment. The previous value is sent a release message.

...

> **nonatomic**
> Specifies that accessors are nonatomic. By default, accessors are atomic.

...

```
[_internal lock]; // lock using an object-level lock
id result = [[value retain] autorelease];
[_internal unlock];
return result;
```